# Using list comprehension to create list and extend in one line

Tags: python

I know there are many similarly titled questions but none of them answer my question which is **why** I cannot use a list comprehension to create a list and extend it with another list comprehension in the same line.

I want to try use:

```
['w' for i in range(7)].extend(['b' for i in range(6)])
```

to generate:

```
['w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

but end up with a NoneType object. I know I could simply use `['w' for i in range(7)] + ['b' for i in range(6)]` or use (in two lines):

```
x = ['w' for i in range(7)]
x.extend(['b' for i in range(6)])
```

but I was just curious as to **why** I couldn't use the extend method on the list created using list comprehension with another list created using list comprehension in the same line.

Thanks.

Comment: `extend` modifies the list in place, it does not return anything

Comment: You *can* use extend in the same line, but it's an in-place method so it returns None.

Comment: The issue here is that the first list comprehension has not been assigned yet. And given that `extend` is computed in-place and returns None, by using extend you are losing the the newly created list

Comment: Oh okay thanks guys now I understand why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **why** is because `extend()` operates on the underlying list and returns None. (It does **NOT** return the extended lsit.)

To illustrate, let's get rid of list comprehensions and just play with lists:

```
>>> foo = [1,2]
>>> bar = [3,4]
>>> result = foo.extend(bar)
>>> print foo
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print bar
[3, 4]
>>> print result
None
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps clarify it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it one-line without `extend`:

```
['w' if i < 7 else 'b' for i in range(13)]
```

Output:

```
['w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```